# Process WaitForSingleObject - responsive UI

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi, process, waitforsingleobject

I am using the following code for understanding how to wait for a Process to end while it's active.
In my code, just when notepad opens, I see the MessageBox.

How do I wait until Notepad is closed, without making my Form unresponsive?

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Const WAIT_INFINITE = -1&
    Private Const SYNCHRONIZE = &H100000

    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long,
   ByVal bInheritHandle As Long,
   ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal hHandle As Long,
   ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

    Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" _
  (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim hProcess As Long
        Dim taskId As Long
        Dim cmdline As String

        cmdline = "notepad.exe"
        taskId = Shell(cmdline, vbNormalFocus)

        hProcess = OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, True, taskId)
        Call WaitForSingleObject(hProcess, WAIT_INFINITE)
        CloseHandle(hProcess)

        MsgBox ("The shelled app has ended.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Must you do it this way or could you more simply use an instance of `System.Diagnostics.Process`  that you `Await proc.WaitForExitAsync()`?

Comment: Thank you for comment! but this is defintely is not working as expected. Please can you post an sample code demoing the WaitForExitAsync?

Comment: Since you are "using the code for understanding the waiting for process", could you temporarily comment out the Notepad execution code? Also, have you tried to run this VB.NET code in debug with Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2):

In .Net Framework / .Net Core, you can use the asynchronous, event-driven, version of [WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit), subscribing to the [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event, which is raised when the  Process you started terminates.

**Note**: The event is raised in ThreadPool Threads. You can set the [Process.SynchronizingObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject) to the current Form instance to marshal the events to the UI Thread.

In .Net Framework, set [[Process].StartInfo.UseShellExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute) to `False`, since the default is `True`.
In .Net Core the default is already `False`.

When the event is raised, the Process has already exited ([HasExited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited) is `True`), so not all the usual information is available. The `Process.StartInfo` (the [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) object) is accessible, plus of course the [ExitTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exittime) and other values (inspect the Process object when the event is raised).

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p = New Process()
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    p.SynchronizingObject = Me
    p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    AddHandler p.Exited,
        Sub()
            Dim processName = p.StartInfo.FileName
            Dim exitTime = p.ExitTime
            p?.Dispose()
            MessageBox.Show("Process exited")
            DoSomethingElseRelated(processName, exitTime)
        End Sub
    p.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: I was working on disabling button when clicked and one notepad instance is opened. Code wise it seems working, but I get an exception in debug mode 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Button1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.''

Code I modified from your answer:
 .... p?.Dispose()
            'MessageBox.Show("Process exited")
            Button1.Enabled = True
            'DoSomethingElseRelated(processName, exitTime)
        End Sub
        p.Start()
        Button1.Enabled = False

Comment: Sure. You can add `[Process].SynchronizingObject = Me`, otherwise the event is raised in a ThreadPool Thread. I've edit the post. -- You should disable the Button before starting the Process.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, a WaitForExitAsync would look like:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim p = Process.Start("notepad.exe")
    Await p.WaitForExitAsync()
    MsgBox ("The shelled app has ended.")
End Sub
```